# GTA IV camera auto-center problem

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I used to play GTA IV couple of years ago, and I remember that somehow I managed to turn of auto-centered camera while walking or running. Now, I decided to complete both DLCs, and also to play on my old saves, but there's no way to turn it off now. I googled alot, alas I couldn't find any information regarding disabling auto-center camera, and no mods to fix it. Any ideas on how to disable auto-centered camera while on foot?